# How to generate Form's OnSubmit attribute with HtmlTextWriter

Tags: c#, html, htmltextwriter

I need the Html will be something like:

```
<form onsubmit="return manipulateForm()">
...
</form>
```

I'm generating it with

```
HtmlTextWriterAttribute key;
string value;

using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(new System.IO.StringWriter(innerBuffer)))
{
    writer.AddAttribute(key, value);
}
```

The problem is that the `HtmlTextWriterAttribute` Enum does not have a definition for **OnSubmit**, hot do i get passed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just saw that the class of `HtmlTextWriter` has override function for  `AddAttribute`

> public virtual void AddAttribute(string name, string value);

So the solution will be like:

```
using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(new System.IO.StringWriter(innerBuffer)))
{
    writer.AddAttribute("onsubmit", "return manipulateForm()");
}
```